# How to test method with Kotlin lambda invocations that return Observable?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, rx-java

How to test method getInfo(id)?

```
fun getInfo(id: String): Observable<List<Item>> =
        interactor.getSomeData { token, userId ->
             repository.getTransaction(token, id, userId)
        }

fun <T> getSomeData(func: (token: String, userId: Long) -> Observable<T>): Observable<T> =
        getAnotherData()
            .flatMap { userId ->
                secureRequest { token -> func(token, userId) }
             }
```

When I try to test this method:

```
@Test
fun getInfoTest() {
        val data = Observable.empty<List<Item>>()

        val function2: (String, Long) -> Observable<List<Item>> = mock {
            on { invoke(token, userId) } doReturn data
        }

        interactor.getInfo(id)
            .test()

        argumentCaptor<Observable<List<Item>>>().apply {
            verify(function2, times(1)).invoke(token, userId)
        }
    }
```

I get an error:

> Wanted but not invoked:
>   function2.invoke("token", 123L);
>   -> at InteractorTest.when getInfoTest(InteractorTest.kt:81)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
>
> Wanted but not invoked:
>   function2.invoke("token", 123L);
>   -> at InteractorTest.getInfoTest(InteractorTest.kt:81)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: You mock a local function and call a method without somehow passing in that said mocked method.

Comment: Observable has method `.test()`. Use it for making your tests :)

Comment: I use it here: interactor.getInfo(id)
            .test()